# How to remove Tweets from User Timeline using PHP

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

i want to delete tweets from user timeline from my app.For that i used:

```
`$retweet1=$twitteroauth->get('statuses/destroy/:id', array('id' => '570916169206509568'));
```

but it showing error:

```
    [errors] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                [message] => Your credentials do not allow access to this resource
                [code] => 220
                )

            )
```

If any one having working example please post it.Thanks

Comment: whose tweets are you trying to delete?

Comment: The error message says a lot: https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/application-permission-model

Comment: i want to remove  my tweets @RamRaider